# I have made a browser. But when I press the maximize button, the components of the form is at its default size. How can i fix it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have made a browser. But when I press the maximize button, the components of the form is at its default size. How can I fix it?

here is the code.

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Devops
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.GoBack();
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.GoForward();
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Refresh();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.GoSearch();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

also, here are some pics
1.App in its normal state:[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b22b9.png)

2.App in its max state:[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt7Wh.png)

Comment: Change the controls `anchor` or their `dock` properties to adjust the controls size and locations as the form size becomes larger

Comment: @Andrei Solero i didnt get you. Im new to visual studio.

Comment: Is that a `WebBrowser` on the bottom center of your form?

Comment: @Andrei Solero Yes, but im going to use TabControl with a WebBrowser.

Comment: I'll post an answer to resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

### You need to adjust the `Anchor` properties of most of those controls to adjust and resize their own properties

On the Properties window, change the WebBrowser `Anchor` to `Top, Bottom, Left, Right`:
[image: Anchor properties for WebBrowser]

For the buttons on your top left corner of the form, change its `Anchor` to `Top, Right`:
[image]

And to adjust the textbox length when the form is resize, change the `Anchor` of the text to `Top, Left, Right`:

[image]